# SWT Text focusLost event sended multiple times

Tags: java, swt

I use a SWT `Text` field and I want to prevent it from being de-focused while it has no Text entered or just white spaces. Also I want to inform the User if that´s the case.

My current solution is that I check it inside a `FocusListener`´s `focusLost`Method. 
But the `focusLost` Event is sended twice so the User will get informed twice and thats not what I want.

So my Questions are:

1. Is it normal that the `focusLost`Event ist sended multiple times? Or is there something wrong in my application?
2. If it is normal: Is there a possibility to ensure the User gets informed just once?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code here works just fine. `SWT.FocusOut` is only fired one:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.addListener(SWT.FocusOut, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            if (text.getText().trim().length() < 1)
            {
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please enter something!");
                        if (text != null && !text.isDisposed())
                        {
                            text.setFocus();
                            text.forceFocus();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Nothing to see here, move along.");
            }
        }
    });

    new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```